# How to Append a tr element into a Table?

Tags: javascript

I tried to append tr into a table with the 2 td elements already appended into my tr element. This is the code I used:

```
var month = 2;
var save = 0;
setInterval(function() { 
month += 1; 
alert("It is the next month."); 
save = 0;
var tr = document.createElement("TR");
var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
var txt1 = document.createTextNode(month);
var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
var txt2 = document.createTextNode("$" + save);
var table = document.getElementById(table1);
td1.appendChild(txt1);
td2.appendChild(txt2);
tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(tr);
document.getElementById("howMuchSavings").innerHTML = "$0"
}, 30000);
function saveMore() {
save += 1;
document.getElementById("howMuchSavings").innerHTML = "$" + save;
}
```

Comment: What's going wrong with the code?

Comment: It wasn't appending the "tr" element to the "table" element.

Comment: Is `table` variable in the scope of the callback of `setInterval`? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No, the console doesn't say anything. But I will try to make the variables in a global scope, just in case. Thanks. Now that I changed the code, it doesn't give me the alert, and the     p element shows "$NaN when I click the button.

Comment: Nvm, it was because I didn't put quotation marks around "table1".

var table = document.getElementById(table1);